# Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null

Tags: php

I'm new here, so forgive me if I'm being silly with this, but I'm working on a PHP Web Crawler ([Check It Out](http://laffyboot.ga/crawler)), and whenever I try to test it, it gives me an output, but also this error:

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/u602323703/public_html/crawler/index.php on line 55
```

Here's line 55 (index.php)

```
if($url!='' && substr($url,0,4)!="mail" && substr($url,0,4)!="java" && array_key_exists($enurl,$found_urls)==0){
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Entirety of the PHP Code:

[Code](http://laffyboot.ga/crawler/indexphp.txt)

**Thanks,
LaffyFX**

*PS: Sorry about not being clear, etc. as I'm not really good with it, I got the script off www.subinsb.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-crawler-in-php (can't post more than 2 links atm)*

Comment: Not enough of your code to troubleshoot, where is $found_urls set?

Comment: Where do you get `$found_urls` from? Whatever is generating that is giving you null instead of the data you're expecting

Comment: `$found_urls` Must be an array and apparently is not like @andrewsi said.

Answer (score 1):

This is meaning that `$found_urls` is not an array.  Before testing if the array key exists you can check if the variable is an array with `is_array` function.  Also, you may want to look at `parse_url`.

I've written crawlers in PHP as well; I ended up with an entire class wrapper to sanely check if a URL had been visited or not.  And another tool to validate and normalize the URLs I had seen as well.